# how to allow editors access to a single plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, editor

I want to allow Editor can access only one plugin

How to do that

This is what i tried

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_page_setup_menu');
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: @Haem i am not able to view this menu in Editor section.